# How to correctly use Linear Approximation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-approximation

I know about the formula L(x, y) = f(x, y) + fxdx + fydy, but I'm having issues applying them in this problem, any help would be appreciated.

In a room, the temperature is given by T = f(x, t) in degrees Celsius, being x the distance from the heater and t the time passed after it has been turned on. Sensors adequately placed in the room register that (1) the temperature is rising at a rate of 1.2 C per minute, 3 meters from the heater, 5 minutes since it was turned on and (2) there is a decrease of 2 C in the temperature per meter, as we get further from the position x = 3, away from the heater, 5 minutes since it has been turned on. Estimate how much colder or hotter it will be at a distance of 2.5 meters from the heater, 6 minutes after it has been turned on. Hint: use linear approximation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.